# How to return a list of react components

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to return a list of components. I tried using

```
const list = [Comp1, Comp2, Comp3] 
const RenderComps = () => {
    return(
        {list.map((comp)=>`<${comp}/>`)}
    )
}
```

nevertheless I cannot render the components properly. I know that I can't call react components by themselves, i.e. just substituting `{list.map((comp)=>comp)}`.

Comment: I think you want something like `list.map((Comp) => <Comp />)`. Also make sure to give each one a `key`

Comment: I need to pass it with capital letters or can I use comp?

Comment: Yeah has to be capital https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the array of components:

```
const list = [Comp1, Comp2, Comp3];
```

Then to render you would render them as JSX, not string literals. Also recall that React components are ***PascalCased***:

```
const RenderComps = () => {
  return list.map((Comp) => <Comp />);
};
```

[User-Defined Components Must be Capitalized](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)